# What is wrong with my expect script?

Tags: linux, bash, expect

I'm trying to learn how to use the [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) command, to help me automate deployment of some software via shell scripts, and figured I start with something simple to get me started.

I've created a file in my home dir called 'foo' using:

`touch foo`

And I've created the following script saved as test.exp

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn rm -i foo
expect "rm: remove regular empty file `foo'?"
send "y\r"
```

When I run the script using `./test.exp`, it spawns the rm command, but it doesn't appear to send the Y and carriage return.

I know I don't have a typo in the expect string, as I've used copy and paste to put in the script.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line after the `send` line:

```
expect eof
```